# How do I reload my comments partial with ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I'm a beginner in Rails and I'm trying to reload a partial when I create a Comment.
I am creating a sort of forum where I have Posts and Comments on Posts.

Here is the situation :
`/views/posts/show.html.erb`

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.title.capitalize %>
  <%= post.content %>

  <%= render 'comments/comment', post: post, comments: post.comments %>

  <%= form_tag(category_forum_post_comments_path(@category, @forum, post), :method => :post, class: 'form newtopic') do  %>
    <%= text_field_tag :content, nil, placeholder: 'Commenter', class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Envoyer", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag(category_forum_posts_path(@category, @forum), :method => :post, class: 'form newtopic') do  %>
  <%= text_field_tag :title, nil, placeholder: 'Titre de votre Post', class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= text_area_tag :content, nil, placeholder: 'Description', id: 'desc', class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Envoyer", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

and then in `/views/comments/_comment.html.erb`

```
<% comments.each do |comment|%>
  <%= comment.content %>
  <%= link_to 'Supprimer', category_forum_post_comment_path(@category, @forum, post, comment),
    method: :delete, class: "btn-danger btn-sm", data: { confirm: 'Etes-vous sûr?' } %>
<% end %>
```

I would like to reload my comment partial on post.
I tried to understand so many posts on stackoverflow and tutorial that I could find online and still have no idea how to do it.

If someone would be kind enough to help me get through this it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

What's the action that you want to trigger that reload? you are showing forms, links, it's not too clear.

Basically, you need to use `remote: true` on the form/link, then add a view for that action with `.js.erb` extension, and, on that view, use javascript to change the content of an specific element.

Something like:

1st, you need to give some unique way to reach the element you want with javacsript:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div id="post_<%= post.id -%>">
    <%= post.title.capitalize %>
    <%= post.content %>

    <div class='comments'>
      <%= render 'comments/comment', post: post, comments: post.comments %>
    </div>

    <%= form_tag(category_forum_post_comments_path(@category, @forum, post), :method => :post, class: 'form newtopic') do  %>
      <%= text_field_tag :content, nil, placeholder: 'Commenter', class: 'form-control' %>
      <%= submit_tag "Envoyer", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag(category_forum_posts_path(@category, @forum), :method => :post, class: 'form newtopic') do  %>
  <%= text_field_tag :title, nil, placeholder: 'Titre de votre Post', class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= text_area_tag :content, nil, placeholder: 'Description', id: 'desc', class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Envoyer", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Note the div with `id=post_x` and the div with class `comment`

Now you can locate it using javacsript:

```
#your_view.js.erb
post = document.getElementById('post_<%= @post.id -%>');
comments = post.querySelector('comments');
```

And finally, also on your view, render the partial and replace comments' innerHTML

```
comments.innerHTML = '<%= j(render partial: "comments/comment", post: @post, comments: @post.comments) -%>';
```

Just a suggestion, use "comments" (in plural) for the name of the partial, since you are rendering all the comments and not just one.

Comment: Thanks arieljuod. I want to reload my partial when I post a comment.

Comment: I have strictly no idea on how to write the js.erb file to do that